# Trouble with Action<T1, T2> and passing multiple parameters

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have this code:

```
        s(x => x.Open());
```

s is a method which calls one parameter, which is perfectly fine, like so:

```
 public void s(Action<p1> action) {}
```

Ignoring the naming conventions, if I make the method like the below:

```
 public void s(Action<p1, p2> action) {}
```

How do I pass in more than one parameter? Out of interest, is there any way to use the params keyword with Action<>?

Also, I am using C# 4.0 so I would be interested to see how it can help me in an way.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to pass multiple parameters to a lambda expression in C# you need to enclose the parameters with parens.  For example

```
s( (x,y) => x.Open(y) );
```

Answer (score 2):

```
s((x, y) => ...);
```